# Can a wizard make an Unarmed Strike?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Obviously, yes, they can. **However, is a wizard *Proficient* with an unarmed strike?**

I was writing up a wizard for a campaign, and when I was going over them I noticed that they don't just get simple weapon proficiency, instead they have a list of weapons they're proficient with. Unarmed Strike isn't on it, and technically it is listed as a simple weapon.

At first I thought it didn't make sense, but when I thought about it, it kind of did. You're basically a scholar, you have almost no weapons training at all-Why would you know how to throw a punch? I know from personal experience, if you've never been shown how to punch correctly (or kick, for that matter) it's not just something everyone picks up.

Comment: Even if they ARE proficient by the rules, I think the idea of them NOT being proficient is way too cool to not make it work like that,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes wizards are proficient in unarmed strike. Note this line from the [SRD Weapons Page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#TOC-Simple-Martial-and-Exotic-Weapons):

> All characters are proficient with unarmed strikes and any natural weapons they gain from their race.

Comment: I can't find it on the page. Could you be more specific where you found it, please?

Comment: @Zach, you can use your browser's search function (ctrl+f) to find the quoted text exactly. It is 4th sentence under the heading: Simple, Martial, and Exotic Weapons. The hyperlink should take you directly to the heading.

Comment: Here's the relevant PRD link: http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/equipment.html#simple-martial-and-exotic-weapons